# ¿Como puedo mandar un pdf generado con DOMpdf a través de correo electronico usando phpmailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer, dompdf

Lo que quiero es generar un factura y mandarla a través de correo electronico mi codigo es el siguiente

aqui genero la factura

```
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf -> loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->setPaper('letter', 'portrait');
$dompdf -> render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
$dompdf -> stream('factura_de_venta_No_'.$no_factura.'.pdf', array('Attachment' => 0));

//aqui la guardo en una variable
$pdf = $dompdf->output();
```

La factura se genera bien me sale en el navegador pero no se guarda en mi localhost ni se manda el correo.

aqui mi codigo de phpmailer

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                      // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
        $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
        $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";  
        $mail->Username   = 'xxxxxx';                     // SMTP username
        $mail->Password   = 'xxxxxx';                               // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
        $mail->Port       = 587;                                    // TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above
    
        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('xxxxxxx', 'xxxxxx');
        $mail->addAddress($correo);     // Add a recipient
    
        // Attachments
        // $mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
        $mail->addAttachment($output, 'aplication/pdf', 'factura_de_venta_No_'.$no_factura.'.pdf', false);    // Optional name
    
        // Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = 'Factura de venta electronica Blue Store Colombia - Tienda de maquillaje';
        $mail->Body    = $message;
    
        $mail->send();

        echo '
        mensaje enviado correctamente
        ';
    }
    catch(phpmailerException $ex)
    {
        echo '
       Ha ocurrido un error"'.$ex.'
        ';
    }
```

Gracias espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad tienes que generar el fichero pdf primero. Ahora mismo el contenido de tu futuro fichero pdf lo estás guardando en $pdf y también en $output, quizás una de las dos sobre. Para generar el fichero, que es lo que phpmailer espera adjuntar, puedes usar lo siguiente:

```
    file_put_contents('tu_fichero.pdf', $dompdf->output());
```

crearás un fichero llamado "tu_fichero.pdf" que será el pdf que quieres adjuntar. Una vez que tengas ese fichero físicamente en el disco, puedes usar el phpmailer así:

```
    $mail->addAttachment('/ruta/tu_fichero.pdf');
```

No necesitas nada más.

Comment: He hecho lo que me has dicho pero no me genera el archivo pdf en la ruta especificada que puedo hacer?

Comment: Por cierto, estoy trabando en sistema operativo MacOS

Comment: si el comando file_put_contents no te devuelve ningún error, el fichero tu_fichero.pdf se ha generado en algún sitio desconocido. Prueba a buscarlo, o mejor aún, a poner la ruta completa en file_put_contents('/Users/tuusuarios/Downloads/tu_fichero.pdf', $dompdf->outut()); y mira a ver si aparece ahí. Yo también uso mac y estos comandos son iguales a linux por lo que te tiene que funcionar.

Comment: Listo lo he logrado muchas gracias!! Lo que pasaba era que tenia file_get_content y no file_put_content error de escritura y no me habia dado cuenta